# How to use variables from other classes?

Tags: actionscript-3

So if I'm making a boolean variable saying from one class. And setting it to true;

class 1

```
yes = true;
```

And the boolean variable goes from class 1 to class 2, and then class 2 applies the action.

class 2

```
if (yes)
{
    do this
}
```

How do I do this? Can you give me a formula? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very generic and vague. In your class 2, do you jsut want to read the value of the variable, or do you only want to execute the code `do this` when the variable changes?

Comment: execute the code when the variable changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `a` is a variable of type `Class1`, it is instantiated and it is accessible in Class2 simple

```
if (a.yes) { do_this(); }
```

should do the trick.